# how to modify viewbox of an svg that is an img tag

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg image in img tag `<img src="image1.svg">`. How can I modify the viewbox property in css without having to change svg file itself?

Comment: read this ; https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG and you will find your answer

Answer (score 11):

You can't do it with CSS, but you can set the viewBox in markup via an [SVG fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG) which would mean adding #svgView(viewBox(x,y,w,h)) to the image URL where x,y,w,h are your viewBox values. E.g.

```
<img src="image1.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,0,100,100))">
```